# Visual Studio code style preference csharp_prefer_braces not working

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

In Visual Studio 2017 I go to Tools > Options > Text Editor > C# > Code Style, and toggle the option "Prefer braces" from yes to no and back.

It does nothing.  The preview below the options always has braces regardless of the setting.

Even an explicit .editorconfig file on `csharp_prefer_braces = false:none` does not change the behavior.

Is this a bug?  Or is some other option overriding?

Answer (score 1):

The property after the ":" will decide how this is treated in VS Code. So using `none` will mean that VSCode doesn't actually enforce this.

The [MS docs here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/editorconfig-language-conventions?view=vs-2019) describe "none" as:

> "**None**": Do not show anything to the user when this rule is violated. Code generation features generate code in this style, however. Rules with none severity never appear in the Quick Actions and Refactorings menu. In most cases, this is considered "disabled" or "ignored".

Perhaps you could try using `csharp_prefer_braces = false:error` instead?